# Insert text on specified row of JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

How can I insert text to a row of my choice ?  I have seen the `insert(String,int)` method, but how does that int translate to a row ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`insert(string,int)` will insert the string at the position represented by the integer. That can be on any line (based on the size of the text area). To put text on a specific row, you can use [getLineStartOffset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#getLineStartOffset%28int%29) to get the position of the beginning of the desired row and then pass that value into `insert(string,int)`